# Embed Java Script Map for VueJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

1. I'm trying to embed a map to my vue component which is written in java script.
2. I downloaded that map from this web link. [Sri Lanka Map](https://jsmaps.io/asia/javascript-map-sri-lanka/)
3. In that map files documentation
   [image]

They say to include some JS and CSS files to the `head` section.

Eg :- `<link href="jsmaps/jsmaps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Where is the `head` section in my template and how do I inject JS / CSS files to that `head` section?

Comment: head section is in the index.html file

Comment: Are you using vue-cli?

Comment: Yes I'm using vue cli

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal I don't want to load it for the all of the users. I only want to load it to the certain users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to manipulate the head section of single page application. Currently you can use Vue plugin named Vue Meta, take a look this repository https://github.com/declandewet/vue-meta.

But if you don't wanna make your hands dirty with that, you can use Nuxt.js, take a look this link https://nuxtjs.org/. Nuxt.js provides an easy way to create a project with Vue.js. You just edit the `nuxt.config.js` file like described here https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head

Even you also can configure head section of specific page as you mention on the comment above.